# Permutation of 10 numbers, position 1 or position 2 not allowed

Tags: probability, permutations

We have a permutation of $\pi$ numbers $\{1,2,...,10\}$. Let $A_1$ be $\pi(1)>1$ and $A_2$ be $\pi(2)>2$. (number on position 1 or 2 must be greater than 1 or 2, respectively). What is the probability of $A_1$ and $A_2$? Are $A_1$ and $A_2$ independent?

I don't know how to approach this problem. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Yes, it should be $\pi(2) > 2$

Comment: You will need to use exclusion-inclusion principle for $P(A\cap B)$ to test independence of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the allocations into disjoint sets:both 1 and 2 are in slots 3-10, thats $8 \cdot 7 \cdot 8!$ and 2 is slot 1 and 1 is in slots 3-10: $8 \cdot 8!$

Answer (score 1):

To figure out the probability $P(A_{1} \mbox{ and } A_{2})$: Count the number of permutations satisfying both, divide by total number of permutations.

To address independence: Does $A_{1}$ being true affect $P(A_{2})$?